# Find indices of line

Tags: tcl

How can I find the indices position of a given line?

`buff_alibaba/Z (BD6BWP540H18P57PDLVT)                                   0.016 &    1.338 r`

I tried with the below line and didn't success

`regexp -all -indices -inline {\S+(?:\s\S+)?\s{1,}} $line`

What I missing?

Comment: What numbers are you wanting to return?

Comment: The result of that command on that input is `{0 71} {72 82} {83 91}`. What did you want that that doesn't provide?

Comment: Means, 
I have 6 columns and I want to get the charters range of each column

Comment: Would `regexp -all -indices -inline {\S+} $line` give you the desired result?

Comment: Yes, :)

Thanks!